# Central support projection and support projection

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I know what is meaning of support projection  and central projection for an element $\omega$ in  Von Neumann algebra $A$. But what is meaning of Central support projection and support projection for a pure state $\rho$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual definition, for a state $\omega$ on $A$, would be
$$
\text{supp}\,\omega=I-\bigvee\{p\in A:\ \text{ projection, }\omega(p)=0\}.
$$
The central version would be the same but only with projections from the centre.

Comment: Given a projection $p$ in $A$ , how to construct a normal state supported on $p$?